# How to remove Visual Studio Code autocomplete suggestion if I type ","?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete

I am programming in jupyter using Visual
Studio Code, but every time I type ","(comma) I get autocomplete suggestions. This is really annoying when writing dictionaries for example. I have tried to solve it by going through every single option in settings>User>Text Editor>Suggestions and the only solution I could find was to disable the "Suggest on Trigger Characters". This unfortunately also disables autocomplete suggestions when I type "."(period) which i want to keep. Is there any way to disable only ","(comma) as a Trigger Character?

[image: Example of the issue]

Comment: Did you try disabling the `Accept Suggestion on Commit Character`?

Comment: But you will lose the `.` completion - I don't think there is a way to disable one autocomplete only - it is language-defined.

Comment: @Mark Yes I tried disabling the Accept Suggestion on Commit Character. This removed the `.` completion as you said, but it did not remove the `,` completion.

Comment: I can't reproduce your question that typing `,` triggered intellisense. Did you add extra settings? Does this question still exist if you [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code)?

Comment: This behavior occurs for me as well, (autocompletions triggered by `,`, with a suggestion list that looks just like the image provided above). It occurs for me specifically in jupyter notebooks. Would love to disable it, because it really gets in the way of regular use.

Answer (score 3):

I found a dirty workaround for this annoying problem:

1. uninstall or disable `ms-toolsai.jupyter` the official Microsoft extension for jupyter
2. install the old deprecated jupyter extension `donjayamanne.jupyter`

In this way you have autocomplete for functions and for the `'.'`, but not for the `','` comma. This can work for you, until the source of the problem found and resolved.

Edit:
The bug is reported on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7880) and it has a **work in progress** status in the [Jupyter: Iteration Plan for November 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8200)

Answer (score 0):

As per https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7880#issuecomment-958594302, rolling back to v2021.8.1236758218 removes the problem until it gets fixed.