# Visual Studio Code autocomplete comma to '%%!'

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

While using the Jupyter extension in VS Code, for some reason, every time I type a comma, VS Code suggests %%! which means I have to hit esc every time in order to make comma separated lists over multiple lines. Can anyone tell me why this is happening or how to stop it? It doesn't happen in a blank notebook, but after running two cells it's back again.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

%matplotlib inline

sns.set()
```

```
def open_hbal(file):
    
    df_balance = pd.read_excel(file) #open xlsx

    t_0 = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1) #set start point for time series

    #add Date and time in fraction steps starting from t_0
    df_balance["Date and Time"] = t_0 + pd.to_timedelta(df_balance["Time"], 
                                                        unit='h')
    
    #convert to datetime object
    df_balance["Date and Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_balance["Date and Time"])

    #replace Index with Date and Time. inplace overwrites df
    df_balance.set_index("Date and Time", inplace=True)

    #remove Time column as it is no longer needed, axis 0 = row, 1 = column
    df_balance.drop("Time", axis=1, inplace=True)

    #df_balance = df_balance / 1000 # convert to kWh

     #replace units in all columns
    #df_balance.columns = df_balance.columns.str.replace(", W", ", kWh")

    df_balance.rename(columns = {"Net losses, W" :"_Net losses, W"}, 
                      inplace = True)
    
    return(df_balance)
```

[image: autocomplete behaviour]

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69394015/how-to-remove-visual-studio-code-autocomplete-suggestion-if-i-type

Comment: Thanks! I had searched but hadn't found anything

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else lands here, other suggested solutions did not work for me on v2021.10.1101450599. As per [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7880#issuecomment-958594302), rolling back to v2021.8.1236758218 removes the problem until it gets fixed.